# Compaq 610 No Ethernet?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet

I have a Compaq 610 laptop that has been unused for the past few years, I decided to make it a small storage/test server, but my ethernet doesn't work. I use Ubuntu Server 12.04, the only way I was able to achieve internet was using an ethernet to usb adapter, but that cuts my speeds from 90mbps down and 90 mbps up to 5 mbps down and 3 mbps up. That results in updates taking 3+ minutes, file transfer goes down to 600 kb/s through FTP. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem. How are you trying to use the Ethernet? How far do you get? What goes wrong?

Comment: I'm plugging the ethernet directly from my router to my laptop, it doesn't even get detected, not a single flash whatsoever, it's like it doesn't even exist.

Comment: Is the ethernet adapter detected by the operating system? Is the driver loaded?

Comment: Alright so I'm checking through "sudo lshw" and it reads:   *-network DISABLED
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: 88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:30:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 10
                serial: 00:25:b3:4e:71:e5
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits

Comment: continued:                 clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:44 memory:e0000000-e0003fff ioport:2000(size=256)

Comment: Check to make sure the network adapter isn't disabled in the BIOS. It might also help to try another cable.

Comment: I looked all through the bios, the only options related to it is related to booting with Ethernet and swtich from LAN/WAN, I disabled and enabled that to see if it helps. I tried 4 different cables, all of them worked on my main desktop.

Comment: Check `dmesg` output for a warning about missing firmware.

Comment: It doesn't seem to show anything about missing firmware, to be honest looking through it twice I couldn't find much of anything about the ethernet other than the previous posted results.

Comment: Extra: So I modified my /etc/network/interfaces and added eth0, it no longer says network disabled, and eth0 seems to be enabled. When my laptop first turns on, once the Ubuntu Server loading splash comes up, the ethernet light flickers 1 time then goes away.

Comment: I worked with it a lot, it's saying "Link = no" when the ethernet is clearly plugged in. I tried 4 different cables and multiple slots on my router."